# Set a specific bit of a number in Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

How can I set a specific bit of a number in Oracle with SQL command?
there is only `BITAND` operator

```
BITAND (DEPENDENCY_MAP, 2)
```

In DEPENDENCY_MAP every bit defines one type dependency.
With this command I can find second bit is seted or not., but how can I modify this bit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To set the bit:

```
UPDATE <table name>
   SET DEPENDENCY_MAP = DEPENDENCY_MAP + 2 -- Set the bit (the row must not have the bit set already)
 WHERE BITAND (DEPENDENCY_MAP, 2) = 0 -- This will match rows that don't have the bit set
   AND <add your own row filters>
```

To clear the bit:

```
UPDATE <table name>
   SET DEPENDENCY_MAP = DEPENDENCY_MAP - 2 -- Clear the bit (the row must have the bit set already)
 WHERE BITAND (DEPENDENCY_MAP, 2) > 0 -- This will match rows that do have the bit set
   AND <add your own row filters>
```

**NOTE:** 
The code above works for positive numbers. I haven't bothered to figure out what would happen if DEPENDENCY_MAP is a negative number, since I assume you don't have negative numbers.